# Does setting a Random objects' seed to a random value make the generator more random?

Tags: java, random

I have this code that simulates 10 coin tosses:

```
public void FlipCoinTenTimes() {
    Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

    // Generate 10 random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        randomNumberGenerator.setSeed(randomNumberGenerator.nextLong());
        System.out.println(randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(2) == 0 ? "Heads" : "Tails");
    }
}
```

Does the setting of the seed to a random long make this method any more random? I.e., more 50/50 than if I were to remove the `setSeed()` line?

Comment: It's "equally 50/50" regardless of the seed. The seed only affects which particular "50/50" sequence you get.

Comment: @immibis I'm not sure. The question I'm asking myself is: "How can changing the seed to a new random value NOT affect the randomness of the generator?"

Comment: @immibis Yes but isnt the sequence the same for a given seed? So changing seed will change the sequence

Comment: Anything that comes out of the generator is not actually random.  You can try to get some actual randomness from high-resolution time or the user's mouse movements or whatever and seed the generator with that, or use SecureRandom for cryptographic guarantees.  Seeding Random with itself effectively just makes the generator more complicated, but not any less deterministic.

Comment: @Ogen Yes. But all sequences will be "equally 50/50", which is what you asked about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, settings the seed like this will not make it 'more random'. The [default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random()) will use a random seed.

The Random class uses a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) to generate a [pseudo random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) series of bits. The state of the random class is contained in something called the seed. When the class is asked for a random number [the seed is updated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next(int)).

It should not affect the distribution to manually reset the distribution of random numbers. If you need a better distribution that is also harder to predict you can use [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html).

Comment: Ofcourse a seed must be initially set but changing the seed every time must have an effect? I've read that certain seeds generate similar sequences so changing the seed randomly should make it more random as a whole. At least this is what I thought.

Comment: @msw that is not correct according to the linked documentation above.

Comment: @Wakahiu Njenga thanks for your edit, but it seems more appropriate in its own answer.

Comment: @vidstige: you are correct. Somehow I thought the question was about Python. Sorry for my error and contradiction.